# Techniques for designing GUI for Android on Qt

Tags: android, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to make my GUI designed on Qt look good on Android devices. Now I'm using widgets with an idea to make universal GUI (for desktop and mobile).
If anybody has an experience in this field can you share some literature, materials, techniques or smth like this?

Thanks!

Comment: First you should understand, that most desktops uses mouse+keyboard, and mobile devices uses sensor screens. That's why it is unreal to design good interface for both. See Windows metro for example of bad usability.

Comment: P.S. look at QML, not widgets.

Comment: You should perhaps ask this at http://ux.stackexchange.com/ (after checking if this hasn't been asked already, and it probably has).

Answer (score 5):

There are two routes I can see:

1. Design separate UI for both desktop (mouse + keyboard) and Android (touch).

   With Qt and QML this is a very strong alternative. Have the application logic in C++ and also in separate Javascript `.js` files. Then write/Design the UI `.qml` files from scratch for both. The downside, or perhaps extra bonus depending on your point of view, is that you have to be pretty careful with the overall architecture, so you can share as much code as possible, and really have just the GUI which is different.
2. Limit yourself to common user interactions. For some UIs this is perfectly fine. There's no universal 1-1 mapping between touch and mouse/keyboard, but there are some common idioms:

   - tap / click for activation
   - long tap / right mouse button for context menu
   - flick / mouse wheel for scrolling
   - pinch zoom / zoom with ctrl+wheel
   - pan with two fingers / drag with mouse button down, or with right button down, or with alt/control keys down

Biggest hurdle for common UI is perhaps selection, especially text selection. What is simple drag or clicks with shift/ctrl pressed when using mouse, becomes complex exercise when using touch, possibly requiring separate icon to enter selection mode, or long tap and selecting right choice from context menu. If selecting things is a central action of your app, you're probably better off going with alternative 1. above, so you can really optimize the touch UI for it, while giving desktop users the "standard" desktop way of selecting things.